# How can I downgrade Safari 6 to 5 in Mountain Lion?

Tags: safari

Is it possible to downgrade Safari 6 to 5 in Mountain Lion? 
I tried to install 5.1.7 but it says it only works with OS X 10.7.

Is there any workaround I can try?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57916/how-do-you-remove-safari-6-on-mac-os-x-10-7-4/59342#59342

Comment: looks like this needs to be revisited as there are two examples given on how to do it where the "No you can't" answer was accepted.

Comment: @dstarh - the best way to get an accept mark to change is making the correct answers better.  As the linked question above is about lion (which shipped with safari 5 - it's a different thing entirely than bolting on a browser that doesn't ship with a newer OS which is the case here). either way, votes and editing can show a "better" answer than even an accepted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't go back with Safari on Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. See this answer:

[How do you remove Safari 6 on Mac OS X 10.7.4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57916/how-do-you-remove-safari-6-on-mac-os-x-10-7-4/59342#59342)

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this answer is for downgrading Safari 6 in Lion only

Yes you can go back to Safari 5.1.7 from Safari 6. I found the uninstaller on [this site](http://steevepatrick.com/). Third from the top is Safari 6 - Lion uninstaller, click this to download, run it, reboot and Safari 5.1.7 will (surprisingly) reappear, I have just done it, no problems though YMMV.