# Is there a Safari 5 download still on apple.com somewhere?

Tags: macos, safari, install

My friend's mother-in-law upgraded to Safari 6 and is now panicking because she doesn't have separate address and search fields. Is there somewhere on apple.com where she can download a Safari 5 installer? She's still running Lion so that shouldn't be an issue.

Unfortunately, telling her to relax and get used to it isn't an option. It's like when my mother's Safari started defaulting to Top Sites and she nearly started crying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this question on Ask Different. [How do you remove Safari 6 on Mac OS X 10.7.4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57916/how-do-you-remove-safari-6-on-mac-os-x-10-7-4)

I had the same problem when I upgraded and was able to switch back following [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/59342/25977).

Comment: I accepted this answer because it pointed to a download link from apple.com.

Answer (score 2):

Safari 5.1.1 for Lion can still be downloaded from [apple.com](http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-2421.20111012.Mxtov/Safari5.1.1Lion.dmg).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

No!
I had the same problem, when I reinstalled Snow Leopard lately.

Apple strangely took all pages for the latest Safari 5 version offline and they also don't deliver Safari 5 updates via the integrated software update anymore.
Currently they're providing no way to update to the latest **Safari version 5.1.7** after a reinstall of an "older" OS X.

BUT, there are some pages providing a mirror for download:

http://mac.softpedia.com/progDownload/Safari-Download-25616.html

Answer (score 0):

You can go to OldVersion.com to search for older versions of software. Safari is included in those.

http://www.oldversion.com/macintosh/Safari.html