# I've installed a new version of Safari and now it refuses to open and doesn't allow me to downgrade

Tags: macos, safari, install

I've installed a new version of Safari and now it refuses to open and doesn't allow me to downgrade.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Someone pointed I had to reinstall the whole system. I'm reading on how to do it right now, but is there a provisory solution?

Comment: Is updating to the OSX 10.8 an option?

Comment: You might want to read this great post here:

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57916/how-do-you-remove-safari-6-on-mac-os-x-10-7-4

Comment: @Jadav not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider marking this question as complete if my answer above helped you.

You might want to read this great post here: apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57916/…