# How do I downgrade my Safari from version 6.1 down to version 6.0.2 on my Mac?

Tags: macos, safari

I need to downgrade my Safari version from 6.1 back down to 6.0.2.
What are the steps?

Comment: Did you made a research before posting this? I've found this within five minutes: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57916/how-do-you-remove-safari-6-on-mac-os-x-10-7-4

Comment: This still leaves the question where to get 6.0.2 from.

Comment: Yes I did research, the link that you speak of states:

Comment: If you are currently running Mountain Lion, or have installed a more recent version of Safari 6 (released anytime after Oct 2012) then you may encounter serious problems when attempting to follow these instructions.
I did research, perhaps you misread what you found.

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade? WHat problems have been introduced by 6.1?

Answer (score 1):

Download link for Safari 6.0.2 is here:

http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/53/02/041-8081/jex01nudh37t8cusghkiy1eki5crm76f4b/Safari6.0.2Mountain.pkg